# Can't understand behaviour of sed command

Tags: command-line, sed, redirect

I have a file test with some data and I am using `sed` command to modify some word in the file and then redirect the output to the same file but after the command is executed the file contains no data. I don't get the reason behind that behavior?

```
$ cat test
foo
bar
123
bar
foo
foo
$ sed 's/foo/bar/' test > test
$ cat test
$
```

Comment: See the linked duplicate. In short, this has nothing to do with `sed`, but with `>` redirection, which is done by bash. File must be opened for writing first (and that's what is done before any command runs), so it will be truncated by shell. What `sed` receives is just empty file that you told bash to overwrite.  Use `-i` flag from `sed` instead of redirection. That will do what you want

Answer (score 5):

It's not best practice to use the same file as both input and output. What happens is that the shell (bash) opens and truncate (the > in your command) the file before sed reads it.

So `sed 's/foo/bar/' test > test.out` would be the right way of doing it.

Comment: Or `sed -i -e 's/foo/bar'` for in-place editing.

Answer (score 2):

`sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' test`

Will replaces `foo` with `bar` and write changes to `test`.

```
$ cat test
bar
bar
123
bar
bar
bar
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster Adited my answer and now it works perfectly fine. Thanks for point out the mistake.

Comment: Thanks, that's better. Though the question isn't so much about a solution as about the reason for the original failure.